# Без нежиті чи без нежитю

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, родовий-відмінок, рід

Як правильно говорити та писати без нежиті чи без нежитю.

[Словник відмінків](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

[image]

Google

> [без нежитю](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8E") Приблизна кількість результатів: 2 140 000
>   [без нежиті](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96") Приблизна кількість результатів: 2 160 000

Comment: Прибрав трекінгову інформацію із запиту. Також зробив точний пошук у лапках, бо Ґуґл може несанкціоновано вважати дві форми слова синонімами і, відповідно, змішувати результати

Comment: @bytebuster дякую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [<sub>2015 ~ роздїл 2, § 44. Поділ на відміни</sub>](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par44)
>
> **II відміна:** а) іменники чол. роду з кінцевим приголосним основи та із закінченням *-о* в наз. відмінку (переважно назви осіб): *бік, велетень, завод, край, майстер, товариш; батько, Дніпро, Петро; татуньо*;
>
> **III відміна:** іменники жін. роду з кінцевим приголосним основи: *вість, любов, міць, річ, розкіш, сіль, тінь*, а також слово *мати*, в якому при відмінюванні з’являється суфікс *-ер-*.

Прийменник *без* вимагає родового відмінку: *без* к/чого.

Зараз *нежить* позначають як чоловічого роду:

> <sub>СУМ 11</sub>
>
> [НЕ́ЖИТЬ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nezhytj), **ю**, *чол.* Запалення слизової оболонки носа, що супроводжується слизисто-гнійними виділеннями, іноді чханням. *Проценко нажив страшенний нежить і цілими днями не виходив з хати* (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 254); *— Я боюсь нежитю. — з грайливою лукавинкою в очах відповіла Віра* (Микола Руденко, Вітер.., 1958, 197).

Тому належить до 2 відміни з відомим противостоянєм між *[~ь]* [*-а* та *-у*](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par48), без всякого *-і* та з лоґічним кінцєм **-у**.

Тому правильно: **без нежит*ю***.

---

Але не лякайте ся, коли зустріли *без нежиті* ві старих писах.

Бо там слово жіночого роду (що лоґічніше особисто для мене).

> <sub>Грінченко</sub>
>
> [Нежить](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32329-nezhyt.html#show_point), *-ті, ж.* = [нежид](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32326-nezhyd.html#show_point). *Після кішка як нап'єшся, — буде нежить.* Мнж. 154. *Напала мене нежить.* Лебедин. у.

Тому і належить третьої відміни.

І відмінювало ся так:

> [<sub>2015 ~ роздїл 2, III відміна §61. Однина</sub>](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#iiividm)
>
> 1. У родовому та давальному відмінках однини іменники третьої відміни мають закінчення **-і**: *вісті, галузі, любові, моці, ночі, осі, подорожі, сталі, тіні, фальші*.

Тому *без нежиті*. Наприклад, таке саме правило для подібних слів було і для [1928](https://r2u.org.ua/node/231)